# What are good, freely available SSA/SCCP resources?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, ssa

This is what I could come up with so far:

gcc related:

- [SSA for Trees](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/)
- [Tree SSA – A New Optimization Framework for GCC](http://www.airs.com/dnovillo/Papers/tree-ssa-gccs03-slides.pdf)
- [Tree SSA A New Optimization Infrastructure for GCC](http://gcc.fyxm.net/summit/2003/Tree%20SSA%20-%20A%20New%20optimization%20infrastructure.pdf)
- [Design and Implementation of Tree SSA](http://mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/gcc/summit/2004/Design%20of%20Tree%20SSA.pdf)

Other:

- [An Implementation of Sparse Conditional Constant Propagation for Machine SUIF](http://lapwww.epfl.ch/dev/machsuif/opt_passes/sccp.pdf)
- [Concurrent Static Single Assignment Form and Constant Propagation for Explicitly Parallel Programs](http://eprints.kfupm.edu.sa/31688/1/31688.pdf)

I've made this a community wiki, so please feel free to add your own resources - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware that GCC no longer uses the SSA described in those papers (Chow's HSSA). Rather it uses an "alias oracle" to disambiguate between memory addresses. It still uses SSA for scalar variables.

Resources:

- I'm surprised you missed: "[A propagation engine for GCC](http://www.airs.com/dnovillo/Papers/gcc2005.pdf)", which described the general framework for SCCP and other sparse conditional analyses used in GCC.
- [Lenart and Sadler](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.1934) extend SCCP to type inference.
- [Patterson](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.7118) extends SCCP to value-range propagation (and also allows copy propagation). I'm pretty sure this is the algorithm GCC uses.
- Finally, if I may be so bold as to suggest [my own short paper](http://paulbiggar.com/research/fit-2009.pdf), which discusses the algorithm, and tries to extend symbolic execution (the core of SCCP) to building SSA as well.

Comment: The link to your own paper is broken.